# Mongo aggregation which finds and updates a document only if certain conditions are met

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a mongo aggregation which does the following, in NodeJS and Express, but can't seem to get it to work. My experience with aggregations is pretty limited so any help would be great.

The 3 bits of data I'll be using to build the query are `key`, `price` and `total_amount` (both are number values, which I will compare the passed value with the stored values)

The idea is to:

1. Find the matching document using the `key` property. If no matching document, create a new document using the passed object.
2. Check if the `price` property is lower than **or** the `total_amount` property I pass is greater than the stored value in my collection.
3. If any of the conditions above are true, update and overwrite the existing record completely. Otherwise, ignore and leave the record as it is.

Any help would be great, thank you.

**Edit** Data examples below

The data will look similar to this, although with more properties which aren't related to my question:

```
[
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "price": 149,
        "total_amount": 40,
        "name": "Item1"
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "price": 225,
        "total_amount": 11,
        "name": "Item2"
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "price": 99,
        "total_amount": 3,
        "name": "Item2"
    }
]
```

I will pass in a single object, and a `total_amount` value, such as :

```js
const total_amount_to_check = 8; // this is the same value for all 3 in this example.
 
const obj1 =  {
        "key": "key1",
        "price": 125,
        "name": "Item1",
        "total_amount": 20,
    };

const obj2 = {
        "key": "key2",
        "price": 400,
        "name": "Item2",
        "total_amount": 45,
    };

const obj3 =  {
        "key": "key3",
        "price": 149,
        "name": "Item3",
        "total_amount": 10,
    };
```

In the 3 examples above, both **obj1** & **obj3** would replace the existing document (`obj1` because the price is lower than the existing price for `key1`, and `obj3` because the existing `total_amount` value is less than the passed `total_value` of 8).

`obj2` would be ignored and would not update/replace the item with `key2.

The collection would look like the below (with the first and last items being updated)

```
[
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "price": 125,
        "name": "Item1",
        "total_amount": 20,
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "price": 225,
        "total_amount": 11,
        "name": "Item2"
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "price": 149,
        "name": "Item3",
        "total_amount": 10,
    }
]
```

Comment: You can do it using update. Why do you want to use an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Please provide sample input data, the aggregation pipeline you tried and desired result.

Comment: I've added some fake sample data to show what I'm trying to achieve. @nimrodserok I was trying to use an aggregation because I thought (with my limited Mongo knowledge) that because this is a multi step process, querying and checking existing values against input values, I had to use an aggregation. I'm happy to learn otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to do it all in one query. For example:

```
const myObjects = [
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "price": 125,
        "name": "Item1",
        "total_amount": 20,
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "price": 400,
        "name": "Item2",
        "total_amount": 45,
    },
    {
        "key": "key3",
        "price": 149,
        "name": "Item3",
        "total_amount": 10,
    }
];
const total_amount_to_check = 8;

const objBulk = thisModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const obj of myObjects) {
  const filter = {
    $and: [
      {key: obj.key},
      {$or: [{price: {$gt: obj.price}}, {total_amount: {$lt: total_amount_to_check}}]}
    ]
  }
  objBulk.find(filter).update({$set: obj });
}
await objBulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way it can be extended so that if there is no document which matches based on `key` alone, it just inserts a new document? Thanks again

Comment: It can be done in one complicated query, but the simple way is to do it with a second query using `bulkWrite` with upsert, where the filter is only on the `key`